# Putting a 16bit register into 8bit address in assembly

Tags: assembly

I need help

For example, `ax` has `FFFF`

```
mov myStack[si] (8bit), ax(16bit)
```

It gave me error:

> wrong parameters: MOV  myStack[si], ax on operands do not match: 8 bit
>   address and 16 bit register

How do I put ax(FFFF) data into myStack, also, is there anyway to move ax to myStack[si].

I know change ax to al, but i need 16 bit on that

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your assembler, you might be able to do the following:

```
    mov  word ptr myStack[si], ax
```

This tells the assembler to use a word-size operand even if `myStack` is declared as a byte.